# Using SCSS to dynamically generate padding and margin enhanced classes

Tags: css, sass

I'm new to this forum and have recently embarked on a journey to learn SCSS for a web project I am taking part in a small business. My specific focus is on dynamically generating enhanced margin and padding CSS classes. To accomplish this, I've developed the following SCSS script:

```scss
$directions: ( 
    "t": "top",
    "r": "right",
    "b": "bottom",
    "l": "left",
    "tr": ("top", "right"),
    "rb": ("right", "bottom"),
    "bl": ("bottom", "left"),
    "lt": ("left", "top"),
    "y": ("top", "bottom"),
    "x": ("left", "right"),
    "yr": ("top", "bottom", "right"),
    "xb": ("left", "right", "bottom"),
    "yl": ("top", "bottom", "left"),
    "xt": ("right", "left", "top") 
);

$behaviors: (
    "max-md": ("max", "md"),
    "max-lg": ("max", "lg"),
    "max-xl": ("max", "xl"),
    "min-xs": ("min", "xs"),
    "min-sm": ("min", "sm"),
    "min-md": ("min", "md"),
    "min-lg": ("min", "lg"),
    "min-xl": ("min", "xl"),
    "only-xs": ("only", ("xs", "sm")),
    "only-sm": ("only", ("sm", "md")),
    "only-md": ("only", ("md", "lg")),
    "only-lg": ("only", ("lg", "xl"))
);

$sizes: ( 
    "xs": 0, // Extra small devices (phones)
    "sm": 576px, // Small devices (tablets)
    "md": 768px, // Medium devices (laptops)
    "lg": 992px, // Large devices (desktops)
    "xl": 1200px // Extra-large devices (large desktops)
);

$rules: ("margin", "padding");

// Mixins for rules
@mixin behavior($rule, $mode, $size, $margin) {
    @if index($mode, "only") {
        @media (min-width: map-get($sizes, nth($size, 1))) and (max-width: map-get($sizes, nth($size, 2))) {
            #{$rule}: $margin;
        }
    }
    @else {
        @media (#{$mode}-width: map-get($sizes, $size)) {
            #{$rule}: $margin;
        }
    }
}

@mixin direction-behaviour($rule, $dir, $mode, $size, $margin) {
    @if index($mode, "only") {
        @media (min-width: map-get($sizes, nth($size, 1))) and (max-width: map-get($sizes, nth($size, 2))) {
            #{$rule}-#{$dir}: $margin;
        }
    }
    @else {
        @media (#{$mode}-width: map-get($sizes, $size)) {
            #{$rule}-#{$dir}: $margin;
        }
    }
}

// Non-decimal rules
@each $rule in $rules {
    @for $i from 0 through 50 {
        // All directions and behaviours
        .m-#{$i} {
            #{$rule}: #{$i}rem;
        }

        // Directions triggered
        @each $dir_key, $dir_val in $directions {
            .m-#{$dir_key}-#{$i} {
                @each $dir in $dir_val {
                    #{$rule}-#{$dir}: #{$i}rem;
                }
            }
        }

        // Behaviours triggered
        @each $beh_key, $bev_val in $behaviors {
            .m-#{$beh_key}-#{$i} {
                @include behavior($rule, nth($bev_val, 1), nth($bev_val, 2), #{$i}rem);
            }
        }

        // Directions and behaviours triggered
        @each $dir_key, $dir_val in $directions {
            @each $beh_key, $bev_val in $behaviors {
                .m-#{$dir_key}-#{$beh_key}-#{$i} {
                    @each $dir in $dir_val {
                        @include direction-behaviour($rule, $dir, nth($bev_val, 1), nth($bev_val, 2), #{$i}rem);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Decimal margins
@each $rule in $rules {
    @for $i from 0 through 50 {
        @for $d from 1 through 999 {
            // Reconstruct decimal value
            $amount: $i + ($d / 10);

            // All directions and behaviours
            .m-#{$i}_#{$d} {
                #{$rule}: #{$amount}rem;
            }

            // Directions triggered
            @each $dir_key, $dir_val in $directions {
                .m-#{$dir_key}-#{$i}_#{$d} {
                    @each $dir in $dir_val {
                        #{$rule}-#{$dir}: #{$amount}rem;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Behaviours triggered
            @each $beh_key, $bev_val in $behaviors {
                .m-#{$beh_key}-#{$i}_#{$d} {
                    @include behavior($rule, nth($bev_val, 1), nth($bev_val, 2), #{$amount}rem);
                }
            }

            // Directions and behaviours triggered
            @each $dir_key, $dir_val in $directions {
                @each $beh_key, $bev_val in $behaviors {
                    .m-#{$dir_key}-#{$beh_key}-#{$i}_#{$d} {
                        @each $dir in $dir_val {
                            @include direction-behaviour($rule, $dir, nth($bev_val, 1), nth($bev_val, 2), #{$amount}rem);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose of this script is to generate classes that follow a particular pattern, as follows:

```css
.{margin or padding}-{direction of the margin or padding (not mandatory)}-{responsive behaviour especification (not mandatory)}-{amount to apply to the margin or padding}{

}
```

For example, the SCSS should generate a class like this:

```css
.margin-xt-only-sm-4_2
```

In this example, the class applies margin to the left, right, and top, only on small screens, with a margin amount of 4.2rem.

However, I've encountered an issue with the code, as it doesn't compile. I've tried using both official and unofficial online SCSS compilers, but neither of them produced an output.

I'd greatly appreciate any assistance in identifying what might be causing this problem and helping me understand how to correct it. If using an SCSS file for this task isn't the best practice, I would also welcome any guidance on alternative approaches.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I it looks like you want to approach styling from the CSS utility class approach – which is a nice approach – but that SCSS script is probably only going to give you headaches, rather than beautiful design I'm afraid.

> If using an SCSS file for this task isn't the best practice, I would also welcome any guidance on alternative approaches.

I wouldn't use SCSS for this. I would recommend you use something like [TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/). It's well thought out and comes with utility classes for basically everything. It has support for breakpoints: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design and hover/focus states: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states. Another neat thing is after the compile step only the classes you actually use in your code will be in the final CSS bundle.